# Is it possible to send two JSON object from PHP to Swift?

Tags: php, json, swift

I wanted to get a multiple **jsonObject** from PHP to my application. The problem is I can't seem to get more than one object to my app. Below is an example of what I wanted to do:

PHP file :

```
<?php 

   echo json_encode([$value1, $value2]);

?>
```

I used the `dataTask` method that looks like below to get the data from the PHP to my Swift application.

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: [Data?], 
response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

 var result = [Conversation]()
 var chck = [String]()  

 do{
     result = try JSONDecoder().decode([Conversation].self, from: data![0]) as Data)
     chck = try JSONDecoder().decode([String].self, from: data![1]) as Data)

  }catch{
       print("error"+error.localizedDescription)

}
        //do something
}
task.resume()
```

Obviously, I didn't get both of the variable. I tried to put `$value1` and `$value2` in an array and then echo it to the application, but apparently it didn't work for me. `data![0]` and `data![1]` gives error. Could anyone lend me a hand please?

Comment: Send it as an array e.g. `echo json_encode([$value1, $value2]);`. What you have at the moment creates an invalid JSON string.

Comment: "I tried to put $value1 and $value2 in an array ... but ... it didn't work" ... Show us what you tried. That's the right basic idea. If `value1` and `value2` are the same structure, then build a normal array and `json_encode` that. If they have different structures, then you probably want to build an associative array (i.e. a dictionary) and `json_encode` that.

Comment: actually I tried to do as what Jon showed above (but i didn't put `[ ]` ) somehow I think the problem comes from the Swift side, I just dont know how to decode the object.. I'll show you what i did, I'll edit the question @Rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm inferring from your Swift code that `$value1` and `$value2` are two different types of results. For collections of heterogenous objects, I'd suggest using an associative array (i.e., a dictionary):

```
<?php 

   echo json_encode(Array("result" => $value1, "chck" => $value2));

?>
```

And you'd parse that with:

```
struct ServerResult: Decodable {
    let result: [Conversation]
    let chck: [String]
}
```

And

```
let serverResult = try JSONDecoder().decode(ServerResult.self, from: data!)
```

Now, given that you haven't shared the details, I'm assuming that:

- `$value1` is a properly structured array of `Conversation`;
- `Conversation` is, itself, `Decodable`; and
- `$value2` is a properly structured array of `String`.

---

I'd also suggest avoiding `data!`, because your app will just crash if there is some server error. I'd suggest you gracefully detect errors, e.g.:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, _, error in    
    guard let data = data, error == nil else {
        print(error ?? "Unknown error")
        return
    }

    do {
        let serverResult = try JSONDecoder().decode(ServerResult.self, from: data)
        // do something
    } catch let parseError {
        print(parseError)
    }
}
task.resume()
```

Comment: That is exactly what I'm having, your assumption is 100% correct!...Thanks for the help , appreciate it